# Extract values between two markers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file with the following information.

document.txt:

> z
>
> -0.01,0.04,-0.04,0,-0.06,-0.08,0.04,0.03
>
> z
>
> 0.1,-0.02,0.1,0.14,0.07,0.05,0.01
>
> z
>
> 0.05,0.05,0.12,0.13,0.08,0.01,0.12,0.11

Essentially, I want my python program to extract the numbers between the markers `z` and add it to a list. So there will be 3 lists, the first will contain the numbers between the first and second `z`, the second list will contain the numbers between the second and third `z` etc...

Here is what I have so far that takes all the numbers, converts them to floats and puts it in a list. Now I need to split it into lists that only contain the numbers between the marker, z.

```
f = open(file_name)

contents = f.readlines()
myList = []

for line in contents:
    line = line.split()
    if 'z' not in line:
        for j in line:
            j = j.split(',')
            for l in j:
                l = float(l)
                myList.append(l)
```

Comment: " I am not too sure where to begin" Start by breaking this into smaller pieces and learn how to do each piece. For example, you need to open a file and read it line by line. Doing just that and printing each line is a perfect place to start.

Comment: I am able to do all of that. I am just not sure how to put all the numbers between the markers into a list @Code-Apprentice

Comment: Please show some code to let us know what you know already then. Then ask a specific question about the place you are stuck. When you say "I am not sure where to begin" I take that literally because you haven't shown any code yet.

Comment: I have edited. @Code-Apprentice

Answer (score 0):

You can set the document.txt in a string and split it on "z". You get a list where each row is a value from that list. So you can make strings from that list and then split it again on ",". That should do the trick

```
#open text file in read mode
text_file = open("document.txt", "r")
 
#read whole file to a string
data = text_file.read()
 
#close file
text_file.close()
 
#split the string
data.split("z")

#remove the first empty value of the list
del data[0]

#since you wanted it in 3 separate list
l1 = data[0]
l2 = data[1]
l3 = data[2]

#split the other 3 lists now and done
l1.split(",")
l2.split(",")
l3.split(",")
```

this gives you the list you wanted.

Comment: Have a look at my edit. Is this heading in the right direction? @Baevern

Comment: @lllakkka Note that this reads the entire file into memory which is fine if is relatively small.